# Champions that have quick cool-down `speed up` spells in "League of Legends"

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm looking for champions that can speed up - my candidates for jungler ^^

Currently I use `Rammus` and `Trundle` for jungle due to their Q and W skills that help them to move faster - which helps moving to the next monster(s) faster. The skills also have a short cool-down time.

I also know that `Nocturne` and `Teemo` also have the skills; though Teemo can speed up in a very short time.

What other champions that you know that can also speed up in short cool-down (maximum 15 seconds) ?

Comment: Umm, you can also solve this issue by Lee Sin. I don't know why you're restricting yourself to movespeed boosts when you can dash and jump on lots of champs. Rek, Lee, Elise, Nid, Gragas, Ekko, Shaco, Tryndamere, Aatrox... There's so many champs you could try that get you to camps faster without a movespeed boost.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Though moving from base to top/bot monster camp and more important, to the opponent camps, we are on our foot.

Comment: It is still doable, just spam the dashes if you have blue / manaless. For example, gragas doesn't have to E onto something, just E forwards for more distance gained quicker. Lee Sin can W to a ward, and can Q to a monster that isn't where he's going and continue to move along. Afraid of the 100 damage? Pop your W. Most competitive junglers right now don't have movespeed boosts, and are still incredibly effective. It's about making the most of your time in the jungle rather, clearing faster can often save more time than moving somewhere faster. Kindred is amazing currently btw. And Rek'Sai.

Comment: Ran out of room. It can also be FAAR more effective to have one short dash/jump over a wall then be able to run around the wall faster. And dashes are great for ganks too, and escaping. Dashes currently are really strong. Get's you over / out of dragon or baron wall for steal/escape. Gets you out of that last turret shot when maybe a movespeed boost wouldn't. Get's you that last AA before turret shot when maybe movespeed wouldn't. Seals an escape over a wall when an opponent can't. Makes an opponent use flash to keep up / escape. You get the point, I don't need to explain more, do I?

Comment: I hope you don't take this the wrong way / offensively btw. I'm really just trying to help. Also I thought of one more important point (have lots more little ones) haha, towards Elise/Lee Sin type of deal, which is they also grant sight of the camps you're going towards without committing to jump in, which can save your @$$ (and has saved mine), especially as you mentioned when going into the enemy camps. Another few I could suggest as well could be Rengar and Kha'Zix. But also I am posting an answer below along the lines you were looking for, champs with movespeed boosts.

Comment: A list question like this will be difficult to keep up to date since new champs will be released in the near and far future that will meet the criteria you are looking for. This makes these types of questions a bad fit for our Q&A format.

Comment: @Ellesedil As you may put the `easy to be changed` condition on top, I believe you just make this community thin with knowledge. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list, asterik'd ones I approve of, double asterik'd ones that really shouldn't jungle (either of those may mean nothing to you, may mean something, I've done it regardless lol). I'm sure this list isn't comprehensive, for one I left out most champions where it's their ult (ahem singed and sivir), but I would suspect that I've hit on the large majority of champions with MS boosts, especially of the viable ones.

Udyr*

Rammus

Evelynn

Hecarim*

Trundle*

Teemo

Akali

Shyvana*

Bard** (unreliable, and definitely would be an insanely difficult to jungle with)

Zilean**

Blitzcrank**

Twitch

Volibear

Skarner*

Kennen**

Draven**

Galio**

Gnar (requires AA's, but also has a jump, and can be even more effective on opponents)

Jayce**

Karma**

Kayle**

Lulu**

Taliyah**? (next to walls, too new to know for sure but come on)

Some other suggestions for dashes / other helpful movement abilities in the jungle (on at the minimum decent junglers): Ekko, Gragas, Lee Sin, Elise, Rek Sai, Kindred, Nidalee (also has a moveboost through brush), Graves, Nocturne, Sejuani, Shaco, Amumu, Jarvan IV, Jax, Maokai, Master Yi (also has a moveboost on ult, and very effective Q jump), Rengar (also has moveboost on ult, and dashes, AND CC), Pantheon, Vi, Zac (pls no), Xin Zhao, Warwick (has a long CD jump on ult, and an unreliable moveboost on I believe his E), Kha'Zix (VERY long range jump on his E, moveboost on ult which grants him stealth as well).

Yet others (junglers that have a dash) you could try (much less popular): Tryndamere, Aatrox, Fizz, Wukong, Fiddlesticks, Diana, Malphite, Shen, Irelia, Riven, Talon.

There you have it. Have fun.

Comment: Lovely list. Got accepted and will be beautified/added with links by me.

Comment: Of note: Bard isn't really bad at jungling. Don't try to kill the camps much though- Chimes give you experience, and killing enemies does too. Bard makes a good Ganking Jungler, using chimes to supplement his mediocre XP from clearing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i know its not exactly what you asked for but if you want to get to the next jungle camps faster how about Rek'Sai as she can burrow holes through the walls can get around fast?. Evelynn has an ability that on a 15 second cool down speeds her up as much as ghost for 3 seconds and removes all slows on her, this ability also cools down 1 second extra every time you damage an enemy champion and resets instantly on a kill or assist.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Hecarim, with his E significantly increasing his movement speed !

Comment: Yeah. Nice Hecarim E! Love it!

Answer (score 1):

Shyvanas W is also a low cooldown movement ability. It has a high uptime (max duration is 7 sec with a base cd of 12sec. So with max cdr you could get a possible uptime of nearly 100%). Keep in mnid though, that the base duration is 3sec, extended by hitting enemies and the ms-boost decays. So as a pure movement ability it is not as strong.

Another classic is Lee Sin. His Q allows for massive mobilityin the jungle.

Answer (score 0):

Love playing Nida jungle.

She can jump very often with her Z and some CDR. You also have more MS while you're in the bush.

If you're good at skillshots, it's pretty easy to gank lanes (you have a nice gap close with the mark).